# HTML and PHP message form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm currently working on a HTML form that uses PHP to send a message to email. I'm testing in MAMP and am unable to get a response after clicking "send message". Any advice would be much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="row half">
        <div class="6u">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u">
            <input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row half">
        <div class="12u">
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="12u">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li class="button form" input type="submit" value="Submit">Send Message</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $to = 'my@email.com';
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    $send_message=mail($to, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

    if($send_message){
        echo "thank you"
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error? You may need to check error log file for more information about any error occurred.

Comment: try turning on error reporting in MAMP, it helps to have it write errors to display when you are starting out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found some errors in ur code

correct this:

```
<li class="button form" input type="submit" value="Submit">Send Message</li>
```

to

```
<li class="button form"> <input type="submit" value="Submit">Send Message</li>
```

correct this:

```
 echo "thank you"
```

to  `echo "thank you";`

Comment: Thanks Ashish, Vishal, Madurai, Vanga and papirtiger - I'll try all these suggestions. Ashish thanks again for the code corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking this in your local server? php mail() function may probably not work in local servers.Check it in some online servers(after correcting the bugs mentioned by @Ashish ).

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<div class="row half">
    <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="6u">
        <input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row half">
    <div class="12u">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="12u">
        <ul class="actions">
            <li class="button form"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sendmessage"/>Send Message</li> // Use name attribute
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Use Name Attribute *

**PHP**

```
      <?php 
    if($_POST['sendmessage']!="")
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
        $to = 'my@email.com';
        $subject = "Contact Form";
        $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
        $send_message=mail($to, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

        if($send_message){
            echo "thank you";
        } else {
            echo "error"; } 
 }
?>
```

*Try this code.*

Comment: <li class="button form" input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sendmessage">Send Message</li> here also dude..it will give syntax error..